# How to prevent people from rewriting my .htaccess file

Tags: apache-http-server

I am using .htaccess file to set some rules about my upload directory, where people are able to upload files. My php code however allows to simply upload .htaccess file through my upload page and it will rewrite original file on my server. How do I stop it?

Solution would be to tell php to rename files when uploaded, or add time stamp to the files so it will never get to rewriting, but I am looking for solution which would not affect my website functionality.

I am using this line in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(php\.ini|\.htaccess) - [NC,F]
```

However doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for help.

Comment: A) do the rules in your `.htaccess` need to live there, or can you put them in a static configuration file instead? B) could you blacklist some filenames in your upload script?

Comment: Anybody being able to upload files seems to me to be your real problem and is what you should address to properly configure (and secure) the server. Either limit the rights of the uploader so that it cannot overwrite protected files, or add authentication and rights so that only those authorized can upload.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I found your B tip useful one. I blacklisted files like htaccess and couple more and it works well. Thanks, didnt think of so obvious solution.
music2myear thanks for tip, however whole point is to allow anybody to upload.